# Has anyone installed Nordvpn in elementary OS 5, if so how?

Tags: software-installation

When I installed Nordvpn on my windows PC it installed easily.  In elementary I downloaded the package and tried to install from the terminal after Gdebi failed to install it.  In terminal it got as far as reading packages but stopped with an "unsupported file" error message.

Comment: Can you please post the exact output of terminal? A screenshot maybe.

Answer (score 1):

Please [download the version of nordvpn](https://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian/pool/main/nordvpn-release_1.0.0_all.deb) and open a terminal window pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and execute the following commands,

```
cd ~/Downloads
sudo apt-get install ./nordvpn-release_1.0.0_all.deb
sudo apt-get update
```

Please note that we are changing directory to "Downloads" because this is where the downloaded files are stored by default and we will have to execute the two following commands from where the file is saved. If you manually saved the norvpn file somewhere else, please change working directory to that directory instead. For example, `cd <some_other_dir>`.

Comment: Thank You Hasan.  After the second command it appeared to be working but after Reading Package Lists, Building Dependancy Tree and Reading Stete Information....Done, it then said "Note, selecting `nordvpn-release` instead of `./nordvpn-release_1.0.0_all.deb`  nordvpn-release is already the newest version (1.0.0)     0 to upgrade,  0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 14 not to upgrade."           That just left me confused as no further command seem to work.

Comment: It says nordvpn is already installed in your system.

Comment: CORRECTION:  The above was on another machine running Ubuntu .  I now have it working following your instructions on the Elementary machine.  Ubuntu is still steadfastly refusing to install nordvpn.  The lack of a GUI makes nordvpn a very bad choice for linux.

Comment: elementary OS Stack Exchange is place where questions are asked about elementary OS. Please don't mind me asking, do mark it as answer if it was helpful. For problems related to ubuntu, please visit [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com).

Answer (score 1):

I followed these [instructions](https://support.nordvpn.com/Connectivity/Linux/1325531132/Installing-and-using-NordVPN-on-Debian-Ubuntu-Elementary-OS-and-Linux-Mint.htm) but do not follow the video it was misleading for me:

```
# installation
cd ~/Downloads

wget -qnc https://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian/pool/main/nordvpn-release_1.0.0_all.deb

sudo dpkg -i ./nordvpn-release_1.0.0_all.deb # make sure there is no other program being installed before running this command

sudo apt update

sudo apt install nordvpn

# then you can login
nordvpn login
nordvpn connect Australia
```